# How to define an unknown typed list inside of the inspector in C# Windows Form Applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, types, casting

I created a custom control for my windows form application. Now I want to use the control several times and specify different lists of objects for every control.

The types of those objects in the lists are different for each list. How do I solve this problem, so that I can choose differently typed lists in the inspector of visual studio?

I hope I was able to explain what I am trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have your `UserControl` be more type specific (i.e. more specific than `Object`) then one option is to use generics as part of your `UserControl`.

E.g.

```
public class MyListControl<T> : UserControl {

  public T GetItem(int index) {
    //...
  }

  public void Add(T item) {
    //...
  }
}
```